# Which openings (black/white) should man play against a player, who is not good at endgame but a tactical beast?

Tags: opening, endgame, positional-play

I'am looking for openings with white and black against strong junior players, which are mostly tactical beasts but not good at endgame.

Comment: what do you normally play?

Answer (score 1):

I typically play double fianchetto (g3,b3 with white and g6,b6 with black); further pawn structure depends on responses; also sometimes playing b4,g4 - but that's more for speed chess; as general idea - some closed position where smart maneuvering matters and no direct encounters in opening if possible - or open 1,2 files and try to exchange few pieces

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee to avoid big tactical complications in a chess game, regardless of the opening / defense played. Anyway, my advice would be to look at Ulf Andersson's opening repertoire with either color to maximize your chanches of playing an (early) endgame.